# CS1519 Error within string calculator kata tdd

Tags: c#

I have been working on some TDD Kata and have it nearly finished but was running into the CS1519 error. VS is telling me where the error is occurring but not sure how to go about fixing the solution. This is my first crack at doing TDD of any kind and looking for some general pointers as well.

I've been on stack overflow looking at other threads about talking about CS1519 but none of them (that I could find) seem to answer my exact question. Also, have checked out Stack Exchange for specific TDD Kata questions but needing more explanation.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace ChallengeCode
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int Main(string number)
        {
            TestUnits();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
                return 0;

            var numberArray = number.Replace('\n', ',').Split(',');

            numberArray = NewMethod(numberArray);

            NonNegValidate(numberArray);

            var numberArrayInt = numberArray.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();


            return numberArrayInt.Where(x => x <= 1000).Sum(x => x);
        }

        private static void TestUnits()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        internal static double Add(string number)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private static string[] NewMethod(string[] numberArray)
        {
            if (numberArray[0].StartsWith("//"))
            {
                var delimiter = Convert.ToChar(numberArray[0].Remove(0, 2).Distinct());
                foreach (var delimiters in numberArray)
                {

                    numberArray[1] = numberArray[1].Replace(delimiter, ',');
                }

                numberArray = numberArray[1].Split(',');
            }

            return numberArray;
        }

        private static void NonNegValidate(string[] numberArray)
        {
            if (numberArray.Any(x => int.Parse(x) < 0))
                throw new Exception($"negatives not allowed {string.Join(" ", numberArray.Where(x => int.Parse(x) < 0))}");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that I am using for Program.cs

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace ChallengeCode
{
    class TestUnits
    {
        public void Add_Number_ReturnsSum(int expected, string number)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, Calculator.Add(number));
        }

        public void Add_NegNumber_Throw_An_Exception()
        {
            const string number = "1\n-2,-3";
            var exception = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => Calculator.Add(number));
            Assert.AreEqual("negatives not allowed -2 -3", exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

> More Details: 
>   [Screenshot of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKInX.png)

Comment: Where is Visual Studio telling you that the error is occurring?

Comment: It's telling me that is occurring in line 1 and Suppression State is Active

Comment: Would be cool if you´d provied the exact error-message and where exactly it occurs.

Comment: Could you post your `Program.cs` code--I'd typically expect this file to contain the static `Main` method that the error says is missing.

Comment: 1: don´t post **images**, but actual **code**. 2: the error does not match the error in the image.

Comment: Code shown does not seem to produce [CS1519](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1519) - please review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your entry point is expecting an array instead of a single string.

I changed your code to this and it compiled.  This is using the first element of your array... but has separate exceptions.

```
    static int Main(string[] number)
    {
        TestUnits();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number[0]))
            return 0;

        var numberArray = number[0].Replace('\n', ',')
                    .Split(',');
    }
```

it's throwing more exceptions for being outside the bounds of this array because I'm not aware of what context this program is being used in.  I assume you have another program feeding the string parameter into this one?

> The Main method can be declared with or without a string[] parameter that contains command-line arguments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/